# PHP equivalent of rbenv/rvm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I've always used Ubuntu's official repositories for installing PHP, but after playing with tools like rbenv and rubybuild for Ruby installations, I am wondering if better tools/techniques exist for installing PHP. Particularly, I'd like to have fine grained control over exactly which PHP version I want to install instead of just getting whatever version Canonical has for me.

It would also be cool to be able to have multiple versions installed simultanously and switch seamlessly between them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this, but as someone who programs adeptly in PHP & adequately in Ruby I can say the main reason Ruby has version control systems is just the utter amount of things that utterly go wrong, fail or break when changing versions. PHP is far more forgiving & understanding of obsoletely methods & functions.

For example, if you make a jump from PHP 5.1.6 to PHP 5.4, there’s relatively little that will break when jumping versions that cannot be fixed fairly quickly. Meaning if something does break it’s fairly clear from the PHP errors to deduce what has gone wrong. And PHP is far more backwards compatible than Ruby.

That said, you can always install multiple versions of PHP modules manually & then just adjust your Apache config, restart Apache & there you go. For example, I had a client that had legacy code that would only work with PHP 5.1.6. So I compiled it from source on Ubuntu 11.04 (and then 11.10 as well as 12.04) but made sure to name the module something like this:

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp516.so
```

Typically the installed PHP module is named something like this:

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

So naming it `libphp516.so` so it encompasses the version number as well allows me to have multiple versions of PHP in place.

With that done, all I need to do to switch versions is edit the `php5.load` located here:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

So it contained lines like this:

```
# LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp.so
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp516.so
```

The commented out first line refers to the already installed version of PHP that is installed via `apt-get`/`aptitude`. The line below it tells Apache to load the `libphp516.so` module. Restart Apache & now PHP 5.1.6 is working.

But I know of know system that will manage that in a more seamless/high-level way.  As I said at true outset, I do not know many people—other than people like me who are forced to do so—who would need such a tool because PHP is far more scalable & respectable when it comes to legacy code than Ruby is. Two different coding philosophies at play.